What happens if an airline reports a high number of involuntary denied boardings to the Department of Transportation?
I read (mirror):

it’s in Delta’s interests to offer more in compensation for a voluntary bump rather than reporting higher involuntary denied boarding numbers to the Department of Transportation.

What happens if an airline reports a high number of involuntary denied boardings to the Department of Transportation?

Seems more like a [travel.se] question than [aviation.se]...

@FreeMan thanks, some people on travel.SE told me to ask here. I have no preferences.
